# Append input value from select Jquery?

Tags: jquery, input, append

I have select with country code

```
<select name="countryCode" id="">
    <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44" Selected>UK (+44)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
    <optgroup label="Other countries">
        <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
        <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

On next field i have enter your phone

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile phone" data="required" id="phone" data-content='Your mobile phone'>
```

What i need is when user select country code to append phone input like this
If user select Algeria (+213), and when he click on input phone, to append his value like
this +213, and then allow him to enter the futher number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#phone').on('focusin', function() {
        var cc = $('select[name=countryCode]').val().replace(/^.*\(([\)]+)\).*$/,'$1');
        $(this).val( cc ).data('cc', cc);
    })
    .on('focusout',function() {
        if( this.value == $(this).data('cc') )
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

**OR:**

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name=countryCode]').on('change', function() {
        var cc = this.value.replace(/^.*\(([\)]+)\).*$/,'$1');
        $('#phone').val( cc )..data('cc', cc);
    });
    $('#phone').on('focusout',function() {
        if( this.value == $(this).data('cc') )
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This works great txanks man, is it possible if user does not enter number, to remove that value when he moves mouse from input #phone. If value of pnone is same as value of select remove value from phone on mouse out?

Answer (score 0):

As above code will set value in phone number but you need to set focus also as updated below

```
$('select').change(function(){
        $('#phone').val( $(this).val() );
        $('#phone').focus();
    });
```

this will help you focus on the field also on change

Comment: Need to perpend the "+" symbol to val()